# How to pass "[Sitecore Mobile SDK] Data from the internet has unexpected format" Exception in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mobile-sdk

I am working on Sitecore Mobile SDK and I have a field named [Email].
I can't insert the data of Email's field into Sitecore because the exception :

> [Sitecore Mobile SDK] Data from the internet has unexpected format

How I can fix this problem ?

**Update :**
I update my question as request. My code as below :

```cs
var builder = ItemWebApiRequestBuilder.CreateItemRequestWithParentPath("/sitecore/content/home")
                          .ItemTemplatePath(@"User Defined/MyTemplate")
                          .ItemName("myItemName");
```

and AddFieldsRawValuesByNameToSet

```cs
builder.AddFieldsRawValuesByNameToSet("Email", txtEmail.Text);
```

**Update 1:**
I have an item named as below (@ symbol):

> myitemname@domain.com

I found my problem is when I update an item by

> UpdateItemRequestWithId

it worked but if I use

> CreateItemRequestWithParentPath

it throw the exception.
I dont know why this.

Comment: What is the code you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` before passing the item name, e.g.:

```cs
string myItemName = "myitemname@domain.com";
var builder = ItemWebApiRequestBuilder.CreateItemRequestWithParentPath("/sitecore/content/home")
                      .ItemTemplatePath(@"User Defined/MyTemplate")
                      .ItemName(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(myItemName));
```

More information in

1. [Sitecore Item Web API Developer's Guide](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc66-71-a4.pdf)
2. [Update an item using the Mobile SDK](https://doc.sitecore.net/mobile_sdk_for_xamarin/managing_content_with_the_mobile_sdk/update_an_item_using_the_mobile_sdk)  article.

Comment: I also have the function use [UpdateItemRequestWithId] and it ok, thanks for "instead of CreateItemRequestWithParentPath" from you.

Comment: To be honest I don't understand your comment ;) Does it mean that my answer is correct and your issue is solved?

Comment: I dont know how to create a new item with [UpdateItemRequestWithId] function because I haven't [item-id-GUID] before. :D

Comment: @KenNguyen is the problem only when you have `@` character in your item name? Have you tried to create item without `@` and `.` characters?

Comment: the problem only when I create an item that have @character. Now I removed this character and pass this exception. But I still hope to know why this. Thank

Comment: Thank you...althought I haven't use [HttpUtility.UrlEncode] but I tested and it's worked !

Comment: Your second link is broken.